# Save and Email VBA code for my current active worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub Mail_ActiveSheet()
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
    Dim FileExtStr As String
    Dim FileFormatNum As Long
    Dim Sourcewb As Workbook
    Dim Destwb As Workbook
    Dim TempFilePath As String
    Dim TempFileName As String
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    Set Sourcewb = ActiveWorkbook

    'Copy the ActiveSheet to a new workbook
    ActiveSheet.Copy
    Set Destwb = ActiveWorkbook

    'Determine the Excel version and file extension/format
    With Destwb
        If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
            'You use Excel 97-2003
            FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
        Else
            'You use Excel 2007-2016
            Select Case Sourcewb.FileFormat
            Case 51: FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
            Case 52:
                If .HasVBProject Then
                    FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
                Else
                    FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
                End If
            Case 56: FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
            Case Else: FileExtStr = ".xlsb": FileFormatNum = 50
            End Select
        End If
    End With

    '    'Change all cells in the worksheet to values if you want
    '    With Destwb.Sheets(1).UsedRange
    '        .Cells.Copy
    '        .Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    '        .Cells(1).Select
    '    End With
    '    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'Save the new workbook/Mail it/Delete it
    TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
    TempFileName = "MyFilename " & Sourcewb.Name & " " & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy")

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With Destwb
        .SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .to = ""
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "MyFilename" & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy")
            .Body = ""
            .Attachments.Add Destwb.FullName
            'You can add other files also like this
            '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
            .Send   'or use .Display
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        .Close savechanges:=False
    End With
```

I already have a piece of code that will save and email my active worksheet. but what i would like to know is if i've got a date in, for example, cell T29 of the active worksheet being sent, how would I add that date to my export filename instead of the `format(now, ddmmyyy)` line?

Answer (score 2):

To get the date from `T29`, then something like this is needed:

```
Format(Range("T29"),"DDMMYYY")
```

If you want to get the date from `T29` of a specific worksheet, then you should specify the worksheet as well - `Format(WorkSheets("SomeName").Range("T29"),"DDMMYYY")`. If you do not specify the worksheet, it takes the one which is selected.

Comment: what i would like it to do is take the date from a particular cell in the worksheet, not use the current system date

Comment: @BrianDavies - I see. How about `format(range("T29"),"DDMMYYY")`?

Comment: thank you, i can do quite a bit in excel, but the coding i need help with. really appreciate it

Comment: @BrianDavies - you are welcome - [What to do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)